# Conditional stored procedure with bool values

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying to assemble a stored procedure to return a set of results.

On my page, I have three checkboxes and a searchbox.

Then in the stored procedure, I have this:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[sp_Search]
   @Bool1 bit = NULL, 
   @Bool2 bit = NULL,
   @Bool3 bit = NULL,
   @SearchTerm nvarchar(30)
As
Begin
   Select 
        [CompanyID],
        [CompanyName],
        [Label],
        [Bool1],[Bool2],[Bool3]     
    From [Contract Companies]
    WHERE (CompanyName LIKE @SearchTerm OR [Label] LIKE @SearchTerm) AND
    if(@Bool1 IS NOT NULL)
    [Bool1] = 'True'
    end 

if(@Bool2 IS NOT NULL)
 AND    [Bool2] = 'True'
    end 

if(@Bool3 IS NOT NULL)
AND [Bool3] = 'True'
    end
```

Something like that, with those three boolean values not true all the time, just when their checkbox will be checked.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: Why not make those parameters non-nullable and just always pass a value? Otherwise you could probably use a [CASE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
create procedure [dbo].[sp_Search]
   @Bool1 bit = null, 
   @Bool2 bit = null,
   @Bool3 bit = null,
   @SearchTerm nvarchar(30)
as
begin
   select 
        CompanyID,
        CompanyName,
        Label,
        Bool1,
        Bool2,
        Bool3    
    from Contract Companies
    where (CompanyName like @SearchTerm or Label like @SearchTerm)
        and (Bool1 = @Bool1 or @Bool1 is null)
        and (Bool2 = @Bool2 or @Bool2 is null)
        and (Bool3 = @Bool3 or @Bool3 is null)
end
```

This will get matching records for each bool when present, and all records otherwise.

It is noted that this [may not be the best performing method](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) of dynamically checking values, but they're bits here ([often not indexed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12888/should-i-index-a-bit-field-in-sql-server)) and I think it fits very elegantly.  There are alternatives discussed in that article.

Answer (score 0):

Option with [**CASE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) expression

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[sp_Search]
   @Bool1 bit = NULL, 
   @Bool2 bit = NULL,
   @Bool3 bit = NULL,
   @SearchTerm nvarchar(30)
As
Begin
   Select 
        [CompanyID],
        [CompanyName],
        [Label],
        [Bool1],[Bool2],[Bool3]     
    From [Contract Companies]
    WHERE (CompanyName LIKE @SearchTerm OR [Label] LIKE @SearchTerm) AND
          [Bool1] = CASE WHEN @Bool1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'True' ELSE [Bool1] END AND
          [Bool2] = CASE WHEN @Bool2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'True' ELSE [Bool2] END AND
          [Bool3] = CASE WHEN @Bool3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'True' ELSE [Bool3] END
```